# How do I know if a date is within the certain period

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

We are capturing attendance data in a certain table primarily capturing the values (userId, startDate, endDate). If a person applies leave on a certain date then only startDate is filled and if he applies for a set of dates then the start/end dates are captured. What query will help me find if a person is taking leave on a certain date (say on the 9th, 12th, 15th of this month)

```
user1, 9/8/2010
user2, 9/9/2010, 9/10/2010
user3, 9/14/2010
user4, 9/15/2010
user5, 9/9/2010, 9/20/2010

users taking leaving on 9th would be user2, user5
users taking leaving on 12th would be user5
users taking leaving on 15th would be user4, user5
```

The query should not contain database specific constructs, it needs to run on
h2 / mysql / postgres using hibernate as the ORM layer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  userId
FROM    mytable
WHERE   '2010-09-09' BETWEEN startDate AND COALESCE(endDate, startDate)
```

Comment: we use hibernate as the ORM layer, is the coalesce command portable across databases

Comment: Its a standard and works in `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `Oracle` and `SQL Server`. Don't know about `H2`, though.

Comment: What does `coalesce` do, exactly?

Comment: @Loadmaster: returns first non-`NULL` argument